# ArcGIS Pro Active Map Metadata Object is Read-only when accessing via ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, metadata

I'm using ArcPy to get the current aprx, active map, then to create an empty metadata object, and populate it with values from a fGDB table, but I cant copy and save it back to the read only map metadata object.

I'm using the metadata object as documented at
[Metadata](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/metadata/metadata-class.htm) in the ArcGIS Pro Online Help.

```
m = aprx.activeMap
m.name = Title  #set the map elements name to the same as the title

# create empty metadata object and populate it with our varibles
new_md = md.Metadata()
new_md.title = 'Title'
new_md.tags = 'Tag1, Tag2'
new_md.summary = 'Summary'
new_md.description = 'Description'
new_md.credits = 'My Credits'
activemap_metadata = md.Metadata(m) #the metadata object for the active map

if activemap_metadata.isReadOnly:
        arcpy.AddMessage("the metadata object for the active map is read only")
else:
        activemap_metadata.copy(new_md)
        activemap_metadata.save()
```

I'm open to ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line:

> activemap_metadata = md.Metadata(m)

with the line:

> activemap_metadata = m.metadata

Answer (score 0):

This works; @Brennan

```
    m = aprx.activeMap
    m.name = Title                                  
    map_metadata = m.metadata                        
    map_metadata.title = Title
    map_metadata.summary = Summary       
    map_metadata.description = Description
    map_metadata.tags = Tag
    map_metadata.credits = Credits
    map_metadata.accessConstraints = Terms
    map_metadata.save()
```